# Swift Delegate Passing Information

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols

I am having trouble conforming to the delegate and passing information between two view controllers. I can't seem to understand what I am doing wrong. I want to be able to pass information from one segmented control in CustomCell VC, to receive and display it after a button has been tapped in the CreateEvent VC. Here is the relevant code:

CustomCell VC:

```
 class CustomCell: CreateEventVCDelegate {

      var ageDescription : String = String() // setup global variable

      func sendageDesciptiongetData(data:String) {
          print(ageDescription)
      }

      @IBAction func ageChanged(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
          switch age.selectedSegmentIndex {
          case 0:
               print("Under 18")
               var ageDescription = "under 18"
          case 1:
               print("Over 18")
               var ageDescription = "over 18"
          case 2:
               print("Strictly over 21")
               var ageDescription = "strictly over 21"
          default:
               print("Other")

    }

}

 }
```

CreateEvent VC:

```
 protocol CreateEventVCDelegate {
      func sendageDescriptiongetData(ageDescription: String)
 }

 class CreateEventVC: UIViewController {

      var delegate: CreateEventVCDelegate?

      @IBAction func saveButtonTapped(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
           var ageDescription = ""

           delegate!.sendageDescriptiongetData(ageDescription)


      }

}
```

Comment: How are you transitioning from one view controller to the next? Via segue in a storyboard or programatically?

Comment: I want to be able to pass ageDescription that is selected from the segmented control to another VC (when the saveButton is tapped)

Comment: But how are you actually transitioning from one VC to another? Are you creating it in code or just through storyboards?

Answer (score 0):

I think you problem is that you need an instance of `CreateEventVC` inside `CustomCell` so you can write:

```
createEventVC.delegate = self
```

inside `CustomCell`.

Anyway I think you don't need a delegation, if you have an instance of `CustomCell` inside `CreateEventVC` you can call a public/internal function of `CreateEventVC` from `CreateEventVC`:

```
cell.sendageDesciptiongetData(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a typo:

You are missing 'r' in `CustomCell` method

```
func sendageDesciptiongetData(data:String)
```

instead of

```
func sendageDescriptiongetData(data:String)
```